# Select Primary Key of entity related by OneToOne

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, criteria-api

A basic entity that has a OneToOne reference to another entity:

```
@Entity
public class Friend {

    // ...

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Friend bestFriend;

}
```

I'd like to build a select query, that contains some of the fields and the best friend id.
In plain SQL it's trivial: `SELECT bestfriendid FROM friend WHERE id = 123`

With JPA criteria API things get very interesting:

```
EntityManager em = ...
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> query = cb.createQuery(Tuple.class);
Root<Friend> root = query.from(Friend.class);
query.multiselect(root.get(Friend_.bestFriend).get(Friend_.id), root.get(Friend_.name));
query.where(cb.equal(root.get(Friend_.id), id));
return em.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
```

This does work for a friend with a best friend set, but the generated SQL is dumb: `SELECT t0.ID, t1.NAME FROM FRIEND t0, FRIEND t1 WHERE ((t1.ID = ?) AND (t0.ID = t1.BESTFRIEND_ID))`
Also it does not work on a fried who has no best friend.
I'd like to see a simple `SELECT t0.NAME, t0.BESTFRIEND_ID FROM FRIEND t0 WHERE t0.ID = ?`.

Can `root.get(Friend_.bestFriend).get(Friend_.id)` be swapped for something else to achieve this?

Comment: Problem is (one of them anyway) that by traversing root.get(Friend_.bestFriend), you are forcing an inner join. If you want an outer join, you'd have to define it in the criteria query and use that join in the select. Next issue is that while EclipseLink knows the FK value == the bestFriend id value and can optimize out the need to join these tables - I don't remember where/when it can do that, or why it wouldn't have tried here. See query keys https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Query_Keys as you can use the fk as a basic mapping in your query

Comment: Hey, this query key docu is measly. But i didn't bother digging in to it, because it seems you have to use non-criteria queries for this. I did stumple upon a solution. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is another field:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "friend_id")
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public Friend bestFriend;

@Column(name = "friend_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public long friendId;
```

This gives me access to the friend id using `root.get(Friend_.friendId)`.